# how bind Dummy network interface od alias ip an LXC guest without bridge?

Tags: networking, lxc

i search any way to bind second public or lan ip direct with Dummy Iface or Alias ip to LXC container WITHOUT bridge interface.

any idea and config example?

(debian)

ip link add eth2 type dummy'

LXC config

```
    # Network configuration
    lxc.net.0.type = phys
    lxc.net.0.link = eth2
    lxc.net.0.ipv4.address = 192.168.1.23/24
    lxc.net.0.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.1.2
    lxc.net.0.flags = up
    #lxc.net.0.name = eth0
    #lxc.net.0.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:85:fb:59
```

this config not works for me..

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question? What is a "dummy iface" or "alias IP"? What do you mean by "bridge interface"? Are you using LXC or LXD (from Snap)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible using the [“IPVLAN” virtual network interface driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/ipvlan.html). It differs from the MACVLAN driver you may already know in that it uses the same MAC address for all virtual interfaces on a master interface, just like multiple IP addresses directly on the master interface would.

On Debian, I use it like this:

```
auto ipvl-main
iface ipvl-main inet manual
   pre-up ip link add link eth0 name ipvl-main type ipvlan mode l2
   post-down ip link delete ipvl-main
```

In LXC, the corresponding configuration looks like this:

```
lxc.net.1.type = phys
lxc.net.1.link = ipvl-main
lxc.net.1.ipv4.address = 192.0.2.4/26
lxc.net.1.ipv4.gateway = 192.0.2.1
lxc.net.1.ipv6.address = 2001:db8:10b:2893::3/128
lxc.net.1.ipv6.gateway = fe80::1
```

Very straightforward. If the network namespace eats the network interface (for example due to `lxc-start` errors) you’ll simply have to recreate it.

Comment: Thanks , your solution works perfectly :)   But i not understand why it not with dummy interface, in fact its similery  iFace.

Comment: A dummy interface is not connected to anything. You cannot use it to connect to a “real” network.